# Prove that if $n^x$ is an integer for every natural number $n$, then $x$ is also an integer.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Question above is self-explanatory.

**Update** 
$n$ is every natural number!

Comment: The statement is not true. Take $n=2$ and $x=\log_23$.

Comment: You're right! Sorry, I updated the question. Sorry for my english

Comment: If I recall correctly, this is an old Putnam problem...